# como puedo realizar operaciones de tiempo en Android studio?

Tags: java, android, datepicker

Buen día. Estoy tratando de hacer un programa para obtener la cantidad de horas extras, nocturnas y festivas que hace un trabajador en la semana, teniendo en cuenta una jornada ordinaria de 8 horas diarias. He investigado y por el momento logre hacer este código el cual me muestra una pequeña app de la cual puedo escoger la fecha y la hora, pero no se convertir esos valores a enteros para hacer las respectivas operaciones. Agradecería que por favor me explicaran como puedo obtener fecha inicial y final con este código y a través de condicionadores como el if obtener ciertos rangos de la jornada y convertir esas horas en números enteros para hacer operaciones y mostrar los resultados al usuario. Gracias...

Sólo pude subir una parte del código, tengo inconvenientes en esta plataforma para subirlo todo.

Este es el código que he podido implementar:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == fechainicial) {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            dia = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            mes = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            año = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    tfechainicial.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);

                }
            }
                    , dia, mes, año);
            datePickerDialog.show();

        } if(v == fechafinal){
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    tfechafinal.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);

                }
            }
                    , dia, mes, año);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }

        if (v == horainicial) {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            hora = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            minutos = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    thorainicial.setText(hourOfDay + "/" + minute);

                }

            }
                    , hora, minutos, false);
            timePickerDialog.show();

        } if (v == horafinal){
            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    thorafinal.setText(hourOfDay + "/" + minute);
                }
            }
                    , hora, minutos, false);
            timePickerDialog.show();
        }
    }
    // metodo para calcular

    public  void calcular(View view){

        int difhoras = (int) (horafinal.getDrawingTime() - horainicial.getDrawingTime());
        final double tiempotranscurrdio = Math.rint(((double) difhoras/3600000)*100)/100;



    }
}
```

Quiero poder mostar el resultado obtenido en "tiempotranscurrido" en un Edittext al presionar un botón.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Tienes que aportar mas cosas en la pregunta, enseñar el codigo que tienes que se vea el esfuerzo que has hecho, explicar donde esta el problema, poner un minimo ejemplo que se pueda reproducir para que te ayude la gente. No puedes poner el enunciado y esperar que alguien te lo haga.

Comment: Buen día, si ya subí el pantallazo del código que he hecho. Es que esta plataforma no me dejaba subirlo como tal.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! El codigo debe ir como texto, las imagenes son dificiles de ver...

Comment: Gracias amigo, es que es la primera vez que uso esta plataforma y aprendiendo a programar también.